# Where does each of my local facilities logs to in Unix?

Tags: ubuntu, logs, haproxy

I was using `local0` facility to log info in `HAProxy`. What I don't understand is in which file each of my facilities (`local0` ... `local7`) logs to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the local6 (and all other local#) facilities in syslog?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90842/what-is-the-local6-and-all-other-local-facilities-in-syslog)

Comment: no, the explanation is pretty vague, it does not helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked answer is pretty clear if you take the time to read and understand it and the `rsyslog.conf` man page but, in short:

Like all other syslog facilities, the rule defining what happens to `local6` log entries is defined in the configuration file(s) for your syslog daemon.

Your tags say you're using `rsyslog` on Ubuntu, so look in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and in `/etc/rsyslog.d/*`.   If `local6` is not defined in any of those files, then define it with a rule like :

```
local6.*    /var/log/local6.log
```

That will log every `local6` message to `/var/log/local6.log`.  Change the priority to `info`, `notice`, `warning`, or higher if you want to reduce log spam. e.g. `local6.notice` instead of `local6.*`. See `man rsyslog.conf` and search for the **SELECTORS** section header.